# How to get the first letter of a post title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, substring

I want to get the first letter of a post title in wordpress, then use `substr` on it to get the first letter by using this snippet but it still displays the full word.

```
<?php 
    $get_title =  the_title(); 
    $ltr_group = mb_substr($get_title, 0, 1);
    echo $ltr_group;
?>
```

Comment: You have the `mb` extension installed? You can just use `substr` if not: https://eval.in/437808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this code maybe useful for you:

```
<?php 
    $get_title =  get_the_title(); 
    $ltr_group = substr($get_title, 0, 1);
    echo $ltr_group;
?>
```

Comment: @MohamedOmar if this answer is useful for you then please accept the answer and upvote. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your the_title() function may not be returning a string
I would start by adding this to your code to ensure that the $get-title variable is in fact a string.

```
echo gettype($get_title), "\n";
```

If that doesn't work maybe try:

```
$ltr_group = substr($get_title, 0, 1);
```

Comment: yes actually it wasn't returning the string.. i should have used this $get_title =  get_the_title();