# Displaying first letters of lastname [wordpress plugin]

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like to display first 3 letters of lastname. I used to use formula on my wordpress theme:

```
<?php 
  $get_title =  get_the_author_meta('user_lastname'); 
  $ltr_group = substr($get_title, 0, 3);
  echo $ltr_group;
?>
```

From ["user2439481"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728889/how-to-get-the-first-letter-of-a-post-title-in-wordpress?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But know I have to put this function in the "Simple User List" plugin.

```
<h3>
        <?php if ( $num_posts > 0 ) { 

            printf( '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s %s</a> <span class="post-count"><span class="hyphen">-</span> %s</span>', 

                get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ),
                sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Read posts by %s', 'simple-user-listing' ), $user_info->first_name ),
                $user_info->first_name,
                $user_info->last_name,
                sprintf( _nx( '1 post', '%s posts', $num_posts, 'number of posts', 'simple-user-listing' ), $num_posts )

            );

        ?>              
    <?php } else {
            echo $user_info->display_name;
        } ?>
</h3>
```

at `$user_info->last_name,` place.

Any great idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the variable before the `printf()` and, replace `$user_info->last_name` by your new variable:

```
<?php if ( $num_posts > 0 ) {

    $get_title =  get_the_author_meta('user_lastname');
    $ltr_group = substr($get_title, 0, 3);

    printf( '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s %s</a> <span class="post-count"><span class="hyphen">-</span> %s</span>',
        get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ),
        sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Read posts by %s', 'simple-user-listing' ), $user_info->first_name ),
        $user_info->first_name,
        $ltr_group,
        sprintf( _nx( '1 post', '%s posts', $num_posts, 'number of posts', 'simple-user-listing' ), $num_posts )
    );
?>
```

Or if you only want to use `substr()` on `$user_info->last_name`:

```
    printf( '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s %s</a> <span class="post-count"><span class="hyphen">-</span> %s</span>',
        get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ),
        sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Read posts by %s', 'simple-user-listing' ), $user_info->first_name ),
        $user_info->first_name,
        substr($user_info->last_name, 0, 3),
        sprintf( _nx( '1 post', '%s posts', $num_posts, 'number of posts', 'simple-user-listing' ), $num_posts )
    );
```